# Find a non-trivial element in the class group of $\mathbb{Q}( \sqrt{−5})$.

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, ideals, class-field-theory, ideal-class-group

a. Find a non-trivial element in the class group of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{−5})$.

b. Show that the class group of $\mathbb{Q}( \sqrt{−5})$ has order two.

For part a: I know that the class group is the factor group $I_K/P_K$, where $I_K$ is the group of fractional ideals of $K$ and $P_K$ is the subgroup of principal fractional
ideals.  So a non-trivial element is represented by a fractional ideal
(e.g. an ideal of $\mathcal{O}_K$) that is not principal (= not generatable
by a single element).

So is $(2, 1 +\sqrt{−5})$ non-trivial element in the class group of $\mathbb{Q}( \sqrt{−5})$? and if so, it's because $(2) = (2, 1 + \sqrt{−5})^2$?

For part b: I know that if $D < 0$ is square-free
and $d = D$ if $D \equiv 1\bmod 4$ then the class group of
a quadratic number field is equal to the class number of an integer. But I don't know how to show that the class group of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{−5})$ has order two.

Comment: Enclose the argument of \sqrt in curly braces { }

Comment: Your first part is correct, although you might want to be more specific about how $(2)=(2,1+\sqrt{-5})^2$ and why that means $(2,1+\sqrt{-5})$ is not principal.

Comment: Can you explain to me why that means $(2,1+\sqrt{-5})$
 is not principal? I know how to show that $(2)=(2,1+\sqrt{-5})^2$

Comment: You need to show that any fractional ideal is either principal or a principal fractional ideal times $(2,1+\sqrt{-5}).$

Comment: and how do I do that?

Comment: @user1052623 Can I explain to you? You are the one who wrote it.

Comment: I mean I know it as a statement but I don't know how to show that. If you could please help me then that would be great

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145868/discussion-between-user1052623-and-thomas-andrews).

Answer (score 1):

Just the first part.

In general, if $R$ is a commutative ring, and $\alpha,\beta\in R,$ then the product of principal ideals is the principal ideal of the product: $\langle \alpha\rangle\langle \beta\rangle = \langle \alpha\beta\rangle.$

So if $\langle \alpha\rangle=\langle 2,1+\sqrt{-5}\rangle,$ then we get $\langle \alpha^2\rangle = \langle\alpha\rangle^2=\langle 2\rangle.$ So $\alpha^2$ must be a factor of two, and hence $\alpha^2\overline{\alpha}^2=(\alpha\overline\alpha)^2\mid 4.$

Since $N(\alpha)=\alpha\overline\alpha$ is an integer, it must be a factor of $2,$ and it can't be $\pm 1,$ because we can easily show our ideal is not the whole ring, so $\alpha$ cannot be a unit.

But is also not hard to show that for $\alpha\in\mathcal O_K,$ it is not possible for $N(\alpha)=\pm 2.$

---

Another approach is to show $2$ is irreducible in $\mathbb O_K.$ It hinges on the same fact: That $N(\alpha)=\pm 2$ is not possible.

If $2=\alpha\beta,$ with $\alpha,\beta\in\mathcal O_K$ not units, then $4=N(2)=N(\alpha)N(\beta).$ If $N(\alpha)=\pm 1,$ then $\alpha$ is a unit. Likewise, for $N(\beta).$ So we must have $N(\alpha)=\pm 2.$

But there is no such $\alpha.$

Since $2$ is irreducible, it cannot be a member of any principal ideals other than $\langle 1\rangle$ and $\langle 2\rangle.$

So $\langle 2,1+\sqrt{-5}\rangle$ cannot be a principal ideal.